# Ubuntu 20.04 only prints partial pdf's sometimes

Tags: printing, pdf

Does anyone have a fix for this problem?

1. Try to print a pdf (multiple printers tried from two different computers - Xerox, Brother & HP, multiple documents)
2. Parts of printed page are blank

I have also tried printing them directly from Firefox, as well as from Document Viewer, but it doesn't make any difference.

Same document prints fine when printing from Windows or a MAC to the same printers.

Comment: What happens if you open the problematic PDF and print it to "Save to PDF" and thus create a copy of the original. Does the new PDF show the full page? If so, can you use this new document for printing?

Comment: The first answer (changing paper size) didn't work, but the second one (re-print to pdf first) DID work. Thank you! Does anyone know why? How I can solve this without using this workaround?

Comment: I will convert my comment to an answer so that you can accept it. As for why it happens, my guess is Windows and Mac (or their corresponding Adobe Reader app) is more forgiving than Ubuntu's Evince (Document Viewer).

Comment: Thanks. You are right - the issue is with Evince. I just installed Okular, and it works fine.

Comment: Please file a bug report for Evince. See [how do I  file a bug report?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) for details and provide them with a sample PDF so that they can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please accept my answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved and help others.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is these files are somehow defective and the Adobe Reader in Windows and Mac is more forgiving than the Ubuntu Document Viewer. A workaround is to create a new PDF file that does not inherit this problem.

## A Workaround

1. Open the document that does not print properly in the default
   **Document Viewer** also known as Evince.
2. Click the Printer icon in the hamburger menu, and select **Print to File**

[image]

3. Make sure the format is set to PDF ("Second" above) and give it a
   file name you want ("Third" above).
4. Click the green **Print** button on the top right to create a copy
   of the PDF file.
5. Open the newly created copy of the PDF and print it as you normally
   would.

Hope this helps